# How to implement SSO in an ASP.NET (.NET 6) razor application with Azure AD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have went through a lot of links in past two weeks but none have solved this problem. If anyone has any idea on how to implement this then please share it here. Most of the links are out dates and straight up are not valid anymore.

I do have a tenant set up Azure. My main problem is that I only want to use Identity for roles and such, and I want to use Azure AD for authentication (SSO).

Any links that are valid or .NET6 razor apps or any info is appreciated.

I tried following the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-tutorial-03-sign-in-users?tabs=visual-studio

But it has to do something with an API. In my application, I will be working with different roles. For this I want to use Identity. However, for main authentication and SSO, I want to use Azure AD. If I try to integrate the identity in my code, then it starts using identity for login instead of Azure AD.

Comment: You can give AD users different roles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following steps to test role based authentication with AAD in .Net 6.

1.Open app registeration.->new registeration.
[image]

2.Fill like below and regisger.
[image]

3.After create ,remember the client ID and tenant ID
[image]

4.Click app roles, create app role. Here you can create a 'cleaner' role and a 'writer' role.
[image]
[image]

5.After this ,go to 'Azure Active Directory', click 'users' you can create a new user here
[image]
[image]
[image]

6.then switch back to 'Azure Active Directory' go to 'enterprise application', then click the app name we just registered.

[image]
[image]

7.choose 'users and groups' ,click 'add user group' .Then you can choose the user you just created ,then select a role to him.
[image]
[image]
[image]

8.Now you can open visual studio. you can create a project with (asp.netc core)razor page template or MVC template. Just be aware in the second step authentication choose the 'microsoft identity platform'.
[image]
[image]

9.in the appsettings. fill in the client ID and Tenant ID we remembered. the domain could be find in the portaol AAD overview page.
[image]
[image]

10. For role test ,we add `[Authorize(Roles = "writer")]` in the Privacy.cshtml.cs.
    [image]

11.Go to the portal 'Active directory` find properties -manage security defatults and disable it, or your will need authenticator for login.
[image]

12. Now run the project. when you log in ,there will be an error that the 'redirect URL doesn't match ' copy the URL. Go to app registeraion - our app- authentication- add platform. choose web ,fill the right URL(it's actually your project URL +'signin-oidc') and check the 'id token'.
    [image]
    [image]

13.Now restart your project. Login in the user you just created. Click privacy. It will show Access denied.
[image]

14.That is because, I assigned the 'cleaner' role to this user. But the privacy page is protected by (roles=writer). if you re-assigned a writer role in step 7. This privacy page will show normally.If you make a breakpoint to check the context. You can find the user claim has the user role you set up in Azure portal after login.
[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps